# How to generate columns dynamically in HTML table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>

   function generateCaseDetails(array, n)
   {
     row = '';

     for( i = 0;i<array.length;i=i+n)
     {
        row+=
        '<tr class = "'+(i%2==0 ? 'even' : '')+'">'+
         for(j = 0; j < n ; ++j)
         {
            '<td><label>'+array[i+j].label+'</label><div>'+array[i+j].value+'</div></td>'+

         }
        '</tr>'
     }

     document.write(row);
   }

   a = 12.5;
   b = 0.3;
   c = 3.4;
   d = 1.2;

   caseDetails = [
     {"label":"30 day exception ratio", "value":a},
     {"label":"30 day exception turn ratio", "value":b},
     {"label":"60 day exception ratio", "value":c},
     {"label":"60 day exception turn ratio", "value":d}
   ]

  generateCaseDetails(caseDetails, 2);
</script>
```

I'm trying to create rows and columns dynamically in a table using above method. It works only with the outer loop, i.e. keeping the columns fixed. I want the no. of columns to be dynamically decided based on the value passed in the parameter of the function. Somehow the inner loop is not working.

Am I doing a syntactical mistake ?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

**Expected output:**

```
 30 day exception ratio  30 day exception turn ratio  
 12.5                    0.3   
 60 day exception ratio  60 day exception turn ratio  
 3.4                     1.2
```

Comment: What do you expect from `array[i+j]`?

Comment: also see :www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp

Comment: @omeinusch, I want the succeeding item in the array to be printed using array[i+j].

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concanate a string with a `for`-loop:

```
    row+=
    '<tr class = "'+(i%2==0 ? 'even' : '')+'">'+
     for(j = 0; j < n ; ++j)
```

This cannot work and your javascript console should give you a reasonable error message.

Just end the first line with the `;`-terminator and prepend the string in the inner loop with `row +=`. Again, end with the `;` instead of the `+`.

Of course, the lone `</tr>` at the end need the preceeding `row +=`, too.

Your inner loop should look like:

```
    row += '<tr class = "'+(i%2==0 ? 'even' : '')+'">';
     for(j = 0; j < n ; ++j)
     {
        row += '<td><label>'+array[i+j].label+'</label><div>'+array[i+j].value+'</div></td>';

     }
    row += '</tr>';
```

Nevertheless, I don't understand what do you want to achieve with `array[i+j]`.

Comment: Thanks @omeinusch for the quick reply. But this too is not working.

Comment: It's a step forward. Please add your expected output in your question as mentioned in my comment above.